# Show that $f\circ \gamma$ is a regular surface.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

> Let $f\colon S_1\to S_2$ be a local diffeomorphism and let $\gamma$ be a regular curve on $S_1$, then $f\circ\gamma$ is a regular surface on $S_2$.

There exists its answer. But I cannot understand it. Please explain the question. Thank you.

> **4.4.4** $d(f\circ\gamma)/dt=D_{\gamma(t)}f(\dot\gamma(t))$ is non-zero because $\dot\gamma$ is non-zero ($\gamma$ is regular) and $D_{\gamma(t)}f$ is invertible (Proposition 4.4.6)

Comment: I think what it means is that $f \circ \gamma$ is a regular curve on $S_2$, no?

Comment: I think, this is a regular curve. I cannot understand its solution. I posted it right now. Please explain the solution. @Marc

Comment: Which part(s) of the solution do you not understand?

Comment: The first one. How to write that question? And why used the equation?  And this equation shows that $f\circ \gamma$ is a regular surface. Isnt it? @john

Comment: You need to input $\LaTeX$ rather than images. I've edited.

Comment: How to translate easily from the image to the writing in MathJax? If there is a easy way, can you tell? @FrankScience

Comment: @B11b It's certainly a handwork to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\gamma: [a,b]\rightarrow S^1$ $t\mapsto \gamma(t):=(\gamma_1(t),\dots,\gamma_n(t))$ is a regular curve on $S^1\subseteq\mathbb R^n$, then the composition $f\circ \gamma: [a,b]\rightarrow S^2$ is a regular curve on $S^2\subseteq\mathbb R^n$, with $f:S^1\rightarrow S^2$ is a local diffeomorphism.

In fact, for all $t\in[a,b]$ the $i$-th component of $f\circ\gamma$ satisfies

$$\frac{d (f\circ \gamma)_i}{dt}(t)=\text{chain rule}=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial \gamma_j}(\gamma(t))\frac{d\gamma_j}{dt}(t), $$

which is non zero as $\gamma$ is regular, i.e. $\frac{d\gamma}{dt}(t)=\left(\frac{d\gamma_1}{dt}(t),\dots, \frac{d\gamma_1}{dt}(t)\right)$ is a non zero vector for all $t\in [a,b]$ and the Jacobian matrix $\left(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial \gamma_j}(\gamma(t))\right)_{i,j}$ of $f$ at $\gamma(t)$ is invertible as $f$ is a local diffeomorphism.